# How to show image list from database in C# windows forms?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sql-server-ce

I am using Sql Server Ce as my database.

The database contains name, id, age, image column.

I can view the data stored in database in a grid view, but is there any way I can view the list of all data along with image?

Answer (score 1):

```
Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytesFromDatabase))
```